# Django Rest Framework serializer field incorrectly named

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I run api request I get a following error:

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `tuple` instance.
> Original exception text was: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'email'.

New user gets inserted in database anyway, email field is filleld properly.

View:

```
class Register(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'name', 'password']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data),
        return user
```

Model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(default='', max_length=10000)
    photo = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    email_verified_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email_token_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email_token = models.CharField(default='', max_length=64)
    password_token_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    password_token = models.CharField(default='', max_length=64)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    last_seen = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'name']

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "User"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I also have custom user manager, but that is probably irrelevant, and works as user does get inserted to database.

Comment: did you try changing your return response to serializers.validated_data?

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in this line:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data),
```

It contains **comma** `,` in the last of line. So `user` become a `tuple` of user instance, not just user instance. It become `(user,)`.
Should return `user` instance.